# Fail To Start Windows Service First Time

Tags: c#, windows-services

I install and start a service with my C# console application.

Installing the service using WinAPI:

```
try
{
    //Open sc manager
    IntPtr sc_handle = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
    if (sc_handle.ToInt32() != 0)
    {
        //Create service
        IntPtr sv_handle = CreateService(sc_handle, svcName, svcDispName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, svcPath, null, 0, null, null, null);

        //If failed
        if (sv_handle.ToInt32() == 0)
        {
            CloseServiceHandle(sc_handle);
            return false;
        }
        else //If succeeded
        {
            CloseServiceHandle(sv_handle);
            CloseServiceHandle(sc_handle);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

Starting the service:

```
//Start the newly installed service
try
{
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController newService = GetService(application.StartupName);

    //If service is stopped or stopping
    if (newService.Status == System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending ||
        newService.Status == System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
    {
        newService.Start();

        newService.WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300.0));
    }

    return true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
```

When setting up a service I install and start it.

When I do this for a very simple service (which does nothing but log its events to a text file), it fails the first time when trying to start the service.

It is the call to WaitForStatus which fails (timeout error).

If I uninstall the service (sc delete servicename), delete the file it logged too and install/start the service again under the same OR a different name, it works fine every time.

If I uninstall the service and search the registry for the service name, there are no results.

I've tried this troubleshooting on 3 different machines (windows 8 and windows 7). I have no other machines to test with and cannot recreate the problem. I even did a system restore to a point BEFORE installing/starting the service for the first time and it still worked without error.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: There should be an exception in the event log when the service fails to start.

Comment: Check windows event viewer *run>eventvwr* if there is any unhandled exception occurs during first start.

Comment: What kind of an error did you see? What was the error message?

Comment: Updated to included the error, my bad. 
It is the call to WaitForStatus which fails (timeout error).

Obviously I could increase the time but I need to be able to recreate the issue first.

Comment: I checked the event logs (Window Logs-> Application).

The first instance of a logged event for my service was "Service started successfully."